# regular expression to avoid placing dot if there is already a dot

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to place a dot after each number at the beginning of the line.

I tried this regular expression:

```
^([0-9]+)=$0.
```

Note that this expression will go as a rule in the server (I can't use any Java code).

It's working when there isn't already a dot, but the problem is its also placing a dot in other places.

for example, if there is a something like `"4.1"` in the text, it's placing a dot and it turns to be `"4..1"`

How can I avoid placing the dot if there is already a dot after the number?

Comment: Which regex dialect is this? Do you have an example of the input and output you want?

Comment: Can you add a sample text and your expected output?

Comment: Input 
-------
Item   Subject   Details

1      Maths     sdfjgsd sjfha sdsjkfh 
2      science   iotpoyigmhpgiojhtypl
2.1    physics    kjghkfghlkfjhflghflgh


I want the output as
--------------------
Item   Subject   Details

1.      Maths     sdfjgsd sjfha sdsjkfh 
2.      science   iotpoyigmhpgiojhtypl
2.1    physics    kjghkfghlkfjhflghflgh

Comment: 1 This is the first line  2 This is the second line 2.1 This is sub line

Comment: I want the output as----- 1. This is the first line 2. This is the second line 2.1 This is the subline

Comment: please note a dot after 1 & 2 in the output, 2.1 as is, my problem is I am getting the output as 2..1 .hope I am clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than worry if there is or isn't a dot following the leading number, just remove the dot *if it's there*, and always put one back:

```
search: ^(\d+)\.?
replace: $1.
```

This has the following effect:

```
"1 This is the first line" -> "1. This is the first line"
"1. This is the first line" -> "1. This is the first line"
"1.1 This is the first line" -> "1.1 This is the first line"
```

Comment: "1 This is the first line" -> "1. This is the first line"    This is not happening  thanks

Comment: The regex is correct, but it could be a syntax thing: I have removed the double escapes from the regex (you haven't told us what took you're using). Try the edited version.

Comment: I've got to assume that if `(?![.\d]) ` didn't work at the end, then all things being equal, the server where he is running this, does not use a regex engine that supports assertions.

Comment: @sln I suspected the same thing. It is still not uncommon to find regex engines that don't support look arounds, especially in databases - AFAIK JavaScript doesn't support look behinds.

Answer (score 0):

Capture pattern == ^([0-9]+)

Replacement pattern == $0.

Comment: Isn't that exactly what OP describes as not working because if places a dot when there is already a dot?

Comment: this will turn `"1. foo"` into `"1.. foo"`

Answer (score 0):

You could use an assertion to restrict the match.
I used a capture group, but you probably don't need to.
Also, make sure you have the *multi-line* flag set so
`^` means beginning of line (not string).

Find:  `^(\d+)(?![.\d])`
Replace `$1.`

Formatted:

```
 ^                      # Beginning of line
 ( \d+ )                # (1), Bunch of digits
 (?! [.\d] )            # If not followed by a dot or another digit
                        # Note -The not digit is to stop it from matching 
                        # the first 12 from 123.3
```

Comment: This stopped from placing the dots where already dot is present, but not placing the dot after each number for example, no dots after 1 & 2 and 2.1 is as is as per my previous comments

Comment: @Sri - Not sure what you mean. It's not replacing with _any_ dots?

Comment: Example::: 1. This is the first line 2. This is the second line   I want a dot to be placed after 1 & 2, That's not happening..thanks

Comment: Oh, well I only see one line in this `1. This is the first line 2. This is the second line` and I don't see any `1 & 2` anywhere. I'll remove my post if it doesn't work.

Comment: It could be the function call on the replacement. Are you adding a dot after the capture group? Also, it could be `$0.` as well, have you tried that?